# Shorthand for initializing members in class constructor

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class with many members like this

```
class someclass
{
    public int number {get;set;}   //repeated a dozen times, with different names of course
}
```

it's constructor should look like this

```
public someclass(int number, ...,)
{
    this.number=number;        //repeated again a dozen times
}
```

is there any shorthand notation to avoid the repetition in the constructor?

Comment: Maybe you could use an array or list instead?

Comment: What if constructor does not provide values for all members?

Comment: @walkhard: yeah, that would be an option, but the actual members aren quite diverse, and adding another layer to wrap them looks more annoying than repeating some lines to me.

Comment: @RohitVats: well, that shouldn't happen

Comment: You can let VS do it for you...outside of your class, instantiate a class with all the parameters you need 'var x = new MyClass(p1,p2,p3,p4,etc.)` and then let VS create the constructor for you - It will fill in all the `this.p1 = p1` automagically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var myInstance = new MyClass
                 {
                    Number = 42,
                    Foo = "Bar"
                 };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use params

```
public someclass(params int[] number)
{
     this.number=number[0];        //repeated again a dozen times
     //...
}
```

Create instance:

```
var c = new someclass(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...);
```